# Nginx gives WordPress wrong path to createFile()

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I had a wordpress site setup & running on an nginx with FastCGI.
Recently I update the theme & I got a problem with my site, which I can't no longer access even administration page.

In the error.log of nginx I found this line:

`CreateFile() "D:/openresty-1.11.2.2-win32/html/wp-contentD:/openresty-1.11.2.2-win32/avada/skin.css.gzip"`

I don't know where in the nginx configuration that gave such path to WordPress.
I do have W3TC page cache enabled and I used below configuration for it.

## BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core

```
 rewrite ^(.*\/)?w3tc_rewrite_test([0-9]+)/?$ $1?w3tc_rewrite_test=1 last;
    set $w3tc_rewrite 1;

    if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $w3tc_rewrite 0;
    }
    if ($query_string != "") {
        set $w3tc_rewrite 0;
    }
    if ($http_cookie ~* "(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle)") {
        set $w3tc_rewrite 0;
    }
    set $w3tc_preview "";
    if ($http_cookie ~* "(w3tc_preview)") {
        set $w3tc_preview _preview;
    }
    set $w3tc_enc "";
    if ($http_accept_encoding ~ gzip) {
        set $w3tc_enc _gzip;
    }
    if (!-f "D:/openresty-1.11.2.2-win32/html/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/$http_host/$request_uri/_index$w3tc_preview.html$w3tc_enc") {
      set $w3tc_rewrite 0;
    }
    if ($w3tc_rewrite = 1) {
        rewrite .* "D:/openresty-1.11.2.2-win32/html/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/$http_host/$request_uri/_index$w3tc_preview.html$w3tc_enc" last;
    }
```

## END W3TC Page Cache core

Comment: Comment all these rewrites and restart nginx that should allow you to be back in admin site at least

Comment: I tried & it didn't work. Though, I checked log files and fix a method re-declaration error & I can now access the admin page. 
But I still get the problem with CreateFile() as the path is incorrect, the theme cannot install its css files.

Comment: See if you can debug why path is being doubled